# Rails 3 Routing - How to use scope to create admin prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scope

I'm using [this Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to create a scope in order to create an "/admin" prefix for some controllers.

So I have a controller named Pages, I want to access it via "/admin/pages".

```
scope "/admin" do
    resources :pages
end
```

That works great, but it is still accessible via "/pages" ... How do I prevent that? (I'm using Rails 3)

Here's my routes file:

```
devise_for :users

scope "/admin" do

    resources :pages

    resources :contents

end

root :to => "index#index"   

match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax for the namespace is correct, but you need to remove the catch-all match from the last line because, according to the default routes.rb file,

```
# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
```

If the requested URL does not match the namespace you have declared, it will still match against the catch-all route at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yeah I sure did. I'm a rails newb so I am probably missing something simple. The routes work, but the old routes still work which is what I don't want.

Comment: Hmm...  I just tried it, so it should work properly as-is.  Have you restarted the web server?  In development mode, you shouldn't have to restart, but it's worth a shot.  Can you post your routes.rb file?

Comment: Updated post with routes file. Thanks for the hand! (Also, I have raked routes and restarted the server)

Comment: I updated the answer to take into account your routes.rb file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this should work

```
namespace :admin do 

  resources :pages 

end
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: This will work, too.  However, a namespace is different from a scope.  The helper names in the admin namespace would be prefixed with admin_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope "/admin", as: :admin do
  resources :pages
end
```