# Rails Engines: Namespaced Polymorphic URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Rails engine, `MyEngine`, that doesn't have an isolated namespace. I'm trying to use the polymorphic helpers to generate links to resources, as per the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes).

An engine route:

```
# config/routes.rb
...
  namespace :admin do
    resources :my_resource
  end
...
```

Example output of `rake app:routes` (remember, this is an Engine):

```
    admin_my_resources GET    /admin/my_resources(.:format)          my_engine/admin/my_resources#index
                       POST   /admin/my_resources(.:format)          my_engine/admin/my_resources#create
 new_admin_my_resource GET    /admin/my_resources/new(.:format)      my_engine/admin/my_resources#new
edit_admin_my_resource GET    /admin/my_resources/:id/edit(.:format) my_engine/admin/my_resources#edit
     admin_my_resource PUT    /admin/my_resources/:id(.:format)      my_engine/admin/my_resources#update
                       DELETE /admin/my_resources/:id(.:format)      my_engine/admin/my_resources#destroy
```

If `my_resource` is an instance of a `MyResource` model with ID `12345`, I'd expect:

```
polymorphic_url([my_engine, :admin, my_resource])
```

to render:

```
/my_engine/admin/my_resource/12345
```

but I was wrong. Instead, I get an exception:

```
undefined method `admin_my_engine_my_resource_path'...
```

So, `polymorphic_url` is trying to use `admin_my_engine_my_resource_path` where it really should be using something more like `my_engine.admin_my_resource_path(my_resource)`

Rails seems to be adding `:admin` the wrong way around... or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried doing this via a scope instead of a namespace?

See this SO article for a better explanation. [Rails Scoped Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581887/rails-3-routing-how-to-use-scope-to-create-admin-prefix)

A good example of this is the devise gem.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer spurred me to look closer at the `namespace` and `scope` and I've ended up creating scopes such as `scope module: "admin", as: "admin"` to get around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake routes` and get the url helper function name from there. You can share the `rake routes` output here also.

Comment: I need the polymorphic route helpers to work. Calling `my_engine.admin_my_resource(my_resource)` works nicely but the equivalent using `polymorphic_url` does not. I'll edit my question to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Just for clarification. Does `polymorphic_url([:my_engine, :admin, my_resource])` work? Just symbolizing the `my_engine`. I cant test this in my machine right now so asking you :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this problem in Rails 5, and found the following general solution.

Given my engine called YamsCore, which generates usual url helpers in form :

```
url_for(yams_core.album_tracks_path)
```

You can write a generic view helper accepting ANY model and generate urls via :

```
path = polymorphic_path([view.yams_core, my_resource])
```

and if you need to specify the action

```
path = polymorphic_path([view.yams_core, my_resource], action: :edit)
```

i.e.

```
path = polymorphic_path([view.engine_prefix, my_resource])
```